# Is there a way to change the block hashing method of private Etherem?

Tags: private-blockchain, hash, hash-algorithm

As all we know, Ethereum hashes blocks by Keccak-256 and this method used in private Ethereum too. Now, if we need to use Keccak-512 for hashing blocks in a PoA private Ethereum (For our project), what is the solution? Is it possible to change the hashing method? Can a private Ethereum have a hash method rather than what Ethereum mainnet has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible and a private Ethereum can have a hash method rather than what Ethereum mainnet has. We should just modify EVM source code for that. EVM is embedded in the web3 provider, For example Geth.